# User input error when asking for a digit (switch case) C

Tags: c, switch-statement

For this program i'm asking the user to enter a digit and it returns the digit you've entered but in another language. I'm using a switch case to utilize this and for user input errors when typing a letter instead of the digits 0-9 it defaults to invalid user input, however, when I enter 10, 11, or 12 which is outside the range it prints out isa which is number 1 which shouldn't be happening. How do I make it so that if the user enters an invalid number outside the 0-9 range it also says invalid input?

Here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("This program will display the Filipino(Tagalog) word for a digit of your choice.\n");
  printf("Enter a digit 0-9: ");
  int digit = getchar();
  switch(digit) {
    case '0' :
      printf("wala\n");
      break;
    case '1' :
      printf("isá\n");
      break;
    case '2' :
      printf("dalawá\n");
      break;
    case '3' :
      printf("tatló\n");
      break;
    case '4' :
      printf("ápat\n");
      break;
    case '5' :
      printf("limá\n");
      break;
    case '6' :
      printf("anim\n");
      break;
    case '7' :
      printf("pitó\n");
      break;
    case '8' :
      printf("waló\n");
      break;
    case '9' :
      printf("siyám\n");
      break;
    default :
      printf("Invalid input\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It's because `getchar()` only retrieves **one** character from standard input. It doesn't read in an entire integer. When you pass `10`, `11` or `12`, your code is actually reading in `1` and leaving the second digit in standard input.

You have at least a couple of options:

1. Read in an *integer* from stdin, using `scanf()` instead of `getchar()`. Take a look at [How can I get an int from stdio in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087062/how-can-i-get-an-int-from-stdio-in-c), this should provide you all the information you need to do it this way, if you choose to do it. You will need to modify your switch-cases to use integer literals rather than character literals for the digits you want to switch on.
2. Alternatively, you could instead read in an entire line of input with `fgets()` and check to make sure it only contains 1 character, then retrieve that first character to use in the switch. This is in keeping with your intent of wanting to switch on *digits*, and also additionally will not fail if you pass a non-integer input to stdin, whereas if using `scanf()`, you need to check the return code to make sure malformed input was not given.
   **I recommend this approach because it is easier to make it fault-tolerant than the other one**.

Answer (score 2):

Echoing what the previous answerer said, `getchar` reads only one character from the standard input stream. Once it gets a character, it assigns it to `digit`.
`getchar` and friends return a value of type `int` in order to be able to return the `EOF` value (which is out of `char` range) so you know when your stream ends. So really `digit` is a character, just with `int` type for that extra little bit of range.

I'll add that `getchar` will leave behind any characters left behind on the input stream that were not used. If you're using this program on the command line and press `3` followed by the enter key in order to get the output `tatló`, the enter key will leave a `'\n'` character (in Linux--I'm honestly not sure if it will be `'\n'` or `'\r'` in Windows) on the standard input stream, which the first `getchar` does not consume.
So you could check this value with another call to `getchar`. Something like this:

```
...
printf("Enter a digit 0-9: ");
int digit = getchar();
if(getchar() != '\n') {
  /*The user typed something after the initial digit, do something, like maybe assigning an invalid value to `digit`*/
  digit = 'a';
}
switch(digit) {
  ...
```

The second call to `getchar` will return `'\n'` if your user entered just a single character; otherwise it will return the second character that the user entered.

This is a suitable solution to parsing a number from user input if you never intend to parse multi-digit numbers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that even on Windows, `'\n'` is the newline character within a C program. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1761086/6177253), in C `'\n'`  is translated to-and-from the native newline character (or character sequence) automatically. The newline character sequence in Windows is CRLF (`'\r\n'`)

Comment: @saxbophone Detail: The end-of-line character(s) is more of a compiler/shell issue than an OS one.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Huh, interesting, why do you say that? Because the choice of the line-ending type was made at the shell level rather than the OS?

Comment: @saxbophone  Yes,  when I run a Cygwin shell on a windows OS machine with a gcc compiled code, its all `'\n'`.  As I see it, the OS really does not get into line-endings much.  Shells and command line processors do.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I can see why you see it that way, after seeing your example, I agree, cheers